# Pdf of scaled Nakagami?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to find the probability distribution function (pdf) of the following

$$Y=a X $$

Given that $$X \sim  \operatorname{Nakagami}(m,1)$$ $$a \,\text{positive constant}$$

Is the pdf of $Y$ $$Y=a\,X\sim \frac{1}{a}f_{X} (y/a)$$
with $$f_X(x)= \frac{2m^m}{\Gamma(m)}x^{2m-1}exp(-mx^2)$$
then $$f_y(y)= \frac{2m^m}{\Gamma(m)}(\frac{y}{a})^{2m-1}exp(-\frac{m}{a^2}y^2)$$

So this mean that $$Y\sim \operatorname{Nakagami}(?,?)$$ What are the new scale and shape parameters

Comment: Your question is meaningless unless you define the functional form for the pdf, and the parameterisation you are using. Also, it is the convention to use upper case notation for random variables.

Comment: Please check my edit..@wolfies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question requesting a proof that $U = X^2 \sim \operatorname{Gamma}$ is a distinct one from your original question and therefore a complete treatment requires a separate answer.

Since the support of $X \sim \operatorname{Nakagami}(m,\Omega)$ is on the positive (or nonnegative) reals, we see that $g(X) = X^2$ is a one-to-one function on this support; thus the relevant transformation is given by $$\begin{align*} f_U(u) &= f_X(g^{-1}(u)) \left| \frac{dg^{-1}}{du} \right| \\ &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} f_X(\sqrt{u}) \\ &= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{u}} \frac{2m^m}{\Gamma(m) \Omega^m} (u^{1/2})^{2m-1} \exp \left( - \frac{m}{\Omega} (u^{1/2})^2 \right) \\ &= \frac{m^m}{\Gamma(m) \Omega^m} u^{m-1} \exp \left( -\frac{m}{\Omega} u \right) \\ &= \frac{(m/\Omega)^m}{\Gamma(m)} u^{m-1} e^{-(m/\Omega)u}, \end{align*}$$ where we can justify $(u^{1/2})^2 = u$ because, again, the support of all random variables here are nonnegative; hence $$U \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(m, \Omega/m)$$ using the **scale** parametrization, and its expected value is $m \cdot (\Omega/m) = \Omega$.

Comment: Great ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

The Nakagami distribution in the general case, according to Wikipedia, is given by $$f_X(x) = \frac{2m^m}{\Gamma(m)\Omega^m} x^{2m-1} \exp\left(-\frac{m}{\Omega}x^2\right), \quad x > 0,$$ for parameters $m, \Omega$.  In the case $\Omega = 1$, and $Y = aX$, then $$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{a} f_X(y/a) = \frac{1}{a} \frac{2m^m}{\Gamma(m)} \left(\frac{y}{a}\right)^{2m-1} \exp\left( -\frac{m}{a^2} y^2 \right).$$ This immediately suggests that $Y \sim \operatorname{Nakagami}(m,a^2)$. Indeed, this is easily seen by observing that $$a (a^{2m-1}) = a^{2m} = (a^2)^m = \Omega^m.$$

Comment: Thanks, do you know what happens to the pdf when I take the square of X, where $X\sim \operatorname{Nakagami}(m,\Omega)$ i,e what is the pdf of $Y=X^2$? I know that it is Gamma but I can't seem to know how to compute its new scale and shape parameter...

Comment: @Tyrone Please refer to the separate answer attached to your question.